# Pass current URL parameters to Cloud Function Python API on IBM Cloud

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm new and trying to create a Cloud Function on IBM Cloud.
My API is working fine on "hello world" only. I need to pass the parameters from URL to manipulate it into my Python API. 
Like:

URL: https://fa75e0fa.eu-gb.apigw.appdomain.cloud/testapi/test1?id=11

I need to pass the value of id=11 at the end of the above URL into my python code (Python 3.70).

I have now this:

```
#
#
# main() will be run when you invoke this action
#
# @param Cloud Functions actions accept a single parameter, which must be a JSON object.
#
# @return The output of this action, which must be a JSON object.
#
#
import sys

def main(dict):
    return { 'message': 'Hello world' }
```

The output is:
{
  "message": "Hello world"
}

I tried:

```
import sys
import urllib3, requests, json
import requests
import os

def main(dict):
    id1=requests.GET.get('id')

    return { 'message': 'Hello world',
             'id': json.loads(id1.text)

    }
```

The output is:

Activation ID:
4e97b3be9b2b49f397b3be9b2b99f34d
Results:
 {
  "error": "module 'requests' has no attribute 'GET'"
}
Logs:

> [   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215661Z    stderr: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):",   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215717Z    stderr: File
>   \"/action/1/src/exec__.py\", line 66, in ",
>   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215722Z    stderr: res = main(payload)",
>   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215725Z    stderr: File
>   \"/action/1/src/main__.py\", line 10, in main",
>   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215728Z    stderr: id1=requests.GET.get('id')",
>   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215731Z    stderr: AttributeError: module
>   'requests' has no attribute 'GET'",   "2020-04-16T11:29:34.215734Z
>   stderr: " ]

Can you please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(args):
    arg1=args.get("arg1")
    myarg=args.get("anotherarg")

    return {"one": arg1, "two": myarg}
```

The parameters are passed in the environment which you can easily access. They are not part of a request structure. **arg1** would be your **id**:

```
import sys
import urllib3, requests, json
import requests
import os

def main(dict):
    id1=dict.get('id')

    return { 'message': 'Hello world',
             'id': id1)

    }
```

Comment: But does it mean that I will have 2 main functions in the script, please?

Comment: I mean I will have  main(dict) and main(args)? please?

Comment: I tried only main(args) with the above code. However, it gives me:{
  "code": "5559f9968f11637895386cd3d5ec57d9",
  "error": "The requested resource does not exist."
} when launching the URL:https://fa75e0fa.eu-gb.apigw.appdomain.cloud/testapi/test1?id=11

Comment: I named it differently. You can name it dict or args or params. Use get() to access the variable you are looking for and which was passed in as parameter.

Comment: And here is a full example which fetches from Wikipedia: https://github.com/data-henrik/chatbot-talks/blob/2020letsmake/functions/wikiExtract.py

Comment: Thanks a lot... Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: Another question please, I know you are expert in Watson Assistant Chatbot too :). I want to save a variable from the user input by enabling Slots and system entities like @sys-number.. I can save number by choosing check for sys-number, or saving date by choosing check for sys-date... But for text/characters please I can't find sys-text or sys-char.. So, how can I use Slots to save text, please? Thanks

Comment: The process is that you mark answered questions as such and upvote them. And you open new questions for new questions. This is not support, but knowledge-sharing... :)

Comment: Thans a lot again... I will open a new question for that.. Hope you will be there to answer :) Upvote Done now :) I will mark question as answered.. Thanks a lot again!